# Why Does My Docking Station Cause Ubuntu to Shutdown and Reboot?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, dell, displaylink, docking

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Dell Latitude E-5470. I want to use a docking station so that I have a dual-monitor setup. I have tried the D3100 and Plugable UD-6950H stations, respectively. Both stations utilize DisplayLink drivers. Both stations cause my machine to shutdown and reboot at random intervals.

### D3100 STATION

Based on the advice of [this post](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/DisplayLink#Displays_disconnect_at_random_intervals_when_using_the_Dell_D6000_docking_station) (about the D6000 docking station), I have commented out `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` from `etc/pulse/default.pa` and rebooted.

Next, I followed steps from [this github post](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/225#issuecomment-753401487), thinking that perhaps there was a problem with the kernel update referenced.

### PLUGABLE UD-6950H

After these attempts and some others, I found [this blog](https://www.mikekasberg.com/blog/2021/08/07/displaylink-docks-and-ubuntu.html#how-do-i-connect-a-displaylink-dock-with-ubuntu) where an Ubuntu user (also using Dell Latitude series PC) discusses connecting display link dock with ubuntu.

I decided to try the station the author recommended and bought the Plugable station. I got a solid day of work out of it with no crashes (March 14) but after that, the crashes came.

I checked the syslogs after one of the crashes and have pasted below. I have only been an Ubuntu user for ~6 months, so I'm still learning a ton. I don't know how to decipher what is going on here but I do see that the `evdi` kernel is involved at the time of the crash (13:07 - 08).

***I would really appreciate any help or feedback that points me in the right direction. I know that it can be done, but I also know that [docking stations for Linux kernels are hard](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2006/ols2006v1-pages-9-18.pdf).***

Thanks in advance.

```
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 at-spi-bus-launcher[6182]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 [6276]: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Stopped target GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Stopped GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 gsd-power[38415]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 gsd-power[38415]: Cannot open display:
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Failed to start GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Stopped GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 gsd-power[38424]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 gsd-power[38424]: Cannot open display:
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Failed to start GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 pulseaudio[5860]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22356.270541] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: off
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22356.271279] evdi: [I] (card0) Notifying display power state: off
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Stopped GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 gsd-power[38436]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 gsd-power[38436]: Cannot open display:
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Failed to start GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Stopped GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 gsd-power[38451]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 gsd-power[38451]: Cannot open display:
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:52 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Failed to start GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Stopped GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 gsd-power[38456]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 gsd-power[38456]: Cannot open display:
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Failed to start GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Requested transaction contradicts existing jobs: Transaction for gnome-session-failed.target/start is destructive (gnome-session-shutdown.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-color.service: Failed to enqueue OnFailure= job, ignoring: Transaction for gnome-session-failed.target/start is destructive (gnome-session-shutdown.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Requested transaction contradicts existing jobs: Transaction for gnome-session-failed.target/start is destructive (gnome-session-shutdown.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-keyboard.service: Failed to enqueue OnFailure= job, ignoring: Transaction for gnome-session-failed.target/start is destructive (gnome-session-shutdown.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Stopped GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Failed to start GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:53 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: gsd-power.service: Failed to enqueue OnFailure= job, ignoring: Transaction for gnome-session-failed.target/start is destructive (gnome-keyring-ssh.service has 'stop' job queued, but 'start' is included in transaction).
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:55 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22359.370764] evdi: [I] (card0) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:55 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22359.370791] evdi: [I] (card0) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:55 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22359.414891] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:55 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Reached target Shutdown running GNOME Session.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:55 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Stopped target Shutdown running GNOME Session.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:55 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Started Restart DBus after GNOME Session shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:56 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22359.414917] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:59 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22363.161775] evdi: [I] (card0) Notifying display power state: off
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:59 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22363.162454] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: off
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:59 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22363.451223] evdi: [I] (card0) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:59 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22363.451261] evdi: [I] (card0) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:07:59 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22363.462060] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:00 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22363.462094] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22374.744474] evdi: [I] (card0) Notifying display power state: off
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22374.744481] evdi: [I] (card0) Notifying display power state: off
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22374.745860] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: off
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:00 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22363.462094] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22374.744474] evdi: [I] (card0) Notifying display power state: off
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22374.744481] evdi: [I] (card0) Notifying display power state: off
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22374.745860] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: off
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (**) Power Button: always reports core events
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) event3  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) event3  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) event3  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) event3  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (**) Power Button: always reports core events
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:11 seth-Latitude-E5470 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[38888]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:12 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22374.745865] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: off
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:12 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22375.812851] evdi: [I] (card0) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:12 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22375.812883] evdi: [I] (card0) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:12 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22375.839000] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:13 seth-Latitude-E5470 kernel: [22375.839012] evdi: [I] (card1) Notifying display power state: on
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:14 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Started GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:14 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[5852]: Reached target GNOME Power management handling.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:26 seth-Latitude-E5470 systemd[38437]: Reached target Shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Mar 23 13:08:54 seth-Latitude-E5470 geoclue[38677]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
```

Comment: Don't just post logvomit. You can see the logs leading up to the crash with `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`. Ask yourself: why did the X server die by losing it's laptop screen? The on/off/on complaints look like un-de-bounced physical connection

Comment: @waltinator your reply is actually precisely why I posted "logvomit". As I said in the write up, I am new to Linux. I can research for myself *if* someone helps me interpret what is important to  look at.

Since I now know it would be *meaningful* to investigate "X server" and get a clue as to what de-bouncing is, I'm going to do that. Thanks to your response to my logvomit.

Comment: Try to "suspend" or "hibernate" your laptop before slamming it into the dock. Read `man pm-is-supported`. Maybe it'll miss all the crazy events, switch flickering, etc. And, if you need to, "power management" will let you run code as the system is going into or coming out of these states.

Comment: "switch bounce" is a physical characteristic of electrical connections. If you watch closely enough, at microsecond intervals, and computers are fast enough,  any connection is jagged, and looks like on/off/on/... until it settles down. Electrical Engineering,  Signal Processing, Digital Design, ... all know this.